# Execute a python script from web browser

Tags: php, python, proxy, squid

I have a Linux proxy server (RaspberryPi-3) running on **squid**. I want to start the squid service using an HTML button on its webpage. With this button, I'm trying to execute a python program to start the squid service:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.system ("sudo service squid restart")
```

But from the web page, it is not working.

What are the other options to get my squid turned on from the browser?

Comment: I've given permission to executethe python script '$sudo chmod +x var/www/html/script.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the PHP tag so i assume that you are using in fact PHP as your web scripting language.

### There is no need for Python, you can directly execute the command from PHP

First you need enable the `www-data` user to run the command without `sudo`.

```
sudo visudo  # you edit the /etc/sudoers with this program
```

Add the following line to the file, then save.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart squid
```

**When the correct permission are set** than this should fairly simple on the PHP side:

```
<?php

shell_exec ("service squid restart")
```

reference for shell_exec: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Maybe the ruleset not applied to the user, can you attempt one more time after a restart? Is PHP do some sort of error message? PHP error messages:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Answer (score 1):

```
# Importing flask module in the project is mandatory 
# An object of Flask class is our WSGI application. 
from flask import Flask 

# Flask constructor takes the name of 
# current module (__name__) as argument. 
app = Flask(__name__) 

# The route() function of the Flask class is a decorator, 
# which tells the application which URL should call 
# the associated function. 
@app.route('/') 
# ‘/’ URL is bound with hello_world() function. 
def start_squid():
    import os
    os.system ("sudo service squid restart")
    return 'Success'

# main driver function 
if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # run() method of Flask class runs the application 
    # on the local development server. 
    app.run()
```

Write a simple Flask api as above.
On your Html button make a get/post ajax call to this flask url so that your squid will be started by the flask controller.

Handle exceptions too in the controller

Comment: He is using PHP, and would like to call a python script, there is absolutely no need to introduce additional complexity to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by using sub-process.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['sudo', 'squid', 'restart'])
```

But when we using **sub-process with sudo** command means it may ask a password to execute the command.